# SOAP error with JBoss 5.1.0GA on OpenJDK 1.7

Tags: exception, soap, jboss, java

I have two servers with the same installation except for OpenJDK.
The working server has

> java version "1.6.0_24"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
>   OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

The non working server has

> java version "1.7.0_09"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.4) (7u9-2.3.4-0ubuntu1.12.04.1)
>   OpenJDK Client VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode, sharing)

In both cases, I have the `jboss-web.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/mycontext</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

And, for my libs to superseed jboss', I have `jboss-classloading.xml` (the war name is "mycontext.war):

```
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0" name="mycontext.war" domain="mycontext" export-all="NON_EMPTY" import-all="true">
```

When I try to make a SOAP request on the non working server (with OpenJDK 1.7) I get the following error:

```
2013-09-11 18:35:45,110 ERROR [org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-6) Exception caught while (preparing for) performing the invocation:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage
```

Note: in both servers, the compilation is the same!

So, this may sound as a dumb question, but can OpenJDK 1.7 be ruining this?
I just find it odd because I have the WS libs in `/WEB-INF/lib` and these should superseed the JBoss bundled libs.

I would like to know why this may be happening. If the solution is reverting to OpenJDK 1.7 I'll be happy to do it, I just don't know how to because the APT sources only have 1.7...